# Openpyxl - Can I create a horizontal bar chart with Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I am able to create vertical bar chart with below code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active 
for i in range(10):
    ws.append([i])

from openpyxl.charts import BarChart, Reference, Series
values = Reference(ws, (1, 1), (10, 1))
series = Series(values, title="First series of values") 
chart = BarChart() 
chart.append(series)
ws.add_chart(chart)
wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")
```

Can I create vertical bar chart with openpyxl? And export the same in image form?

Comment: Should be openpyx.chart instead of openpyxl.charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best chart support is currently in the excellent [Xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) library. Improvements are coming to openpyxl, but as long as you only need to write files then Xlsxwriter is currently the best library.

As both libraries only generate the XML files, you cannot export the chart as an image. You might be able to this by remote control using [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/) but otherwise you should look at one of the visualisation libraries such as MatPlotLib.

Comment: Can i get reference to worksheet using index and start writing. After creating new workbook with N sheets i need to iterate all worksheets with index and write. Can I accomplish it with xlswriter?

Comment: I had a look already. Thanks anyways. Thought if can get quick idea by asking .